# Getting error in accessing SQLite database in android

Tags: android, sqlite

I have tried a lot for the code of how to display data from assets folder in android project but i am unable to do this. please help me to get out of this problem.

Thanks for any help
 EDIT:-
 My adapter class

```
    import java.io.FileOutputStream;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.InputStream;
    import java.io.OutputStream;

    import android.content.Context;
    import android.database.Cursor;
    import android.database.SQLException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException;
    import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
    import android.util.Log;

    public class DBAdapter extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.mynwedb/databases/wbty";

        private static String DB_NAME = "wbty";

        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

        private final Context myContext;

        public DBAdapter(Context context) 
        {
            super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
            this.myContext = context;
        }

        public void createDataBase() throws IOException{
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

            if(dbExist)
            {
                Log.i("DB....", "database available....");
            }
            else
            {
                this.getWritableDatabase();

                try {

                    copyDataBase();

                } catch (IOException e) {

                    throw new Error("Error copying database");

                }

                Log.i("DB..", "database created.....");
            }   

        }


        public boolean checkDataBase(){

            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

            try{

                String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

            }catch(SQLiteException e){

                Log.e("CheckDb","DB not found");
                //database does't exist yet.

                if(checkDB != null){

                    checkDB.close();

                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if(checkDB != null){

                    checkDB.close();

                } 
                this.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;

        }




        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException{

            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;

            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0){

                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }

            myOutput.flush();

            myOutput.close();

            myInput.close();

        }

        public SQLiteDatabase openDataBase() throws SQLException{

            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

            return myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }


        @Override

        public synchronized void close() {

            if(myDataBase != null)

                myDataBase.close();

            super.close();

        }

        @Override

        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        }

        @Override

        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {


        }  


        public void getData()
        {
            SQLiteDatabase myDB ;
            Cursor cursor ;
            try {

                myDB=this.openDataBase();                   

                cursor=myDB.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM descriptions",null);


                if (cursor != null ) {
                    if  (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                        do {

                            // put your code to get data from cursor                      

                        }while (cursor.moveToNext());
                    }

                }



                if(cursor != null)
                {
                    myDB.close();
                    cursor.close();
                }                      
            }catch(SQLException sqle){

                throw sqle;

            }


        }
    }
```

And MyActivity class:-

```
import java.io.IOException;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DBAdapter myDbHelper = new DBAdapter(MainActivity.this); 
        try 
        {
            myDbHelper.createDataBase();
        }catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        finally
        {
            myDbHelper.close();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

}
```

I have kept db file in assets folder.

Comment: show us relevant part of your code.

Comment: do you want to fetch data from asset folder or using sqlite database, paste  some code here. whatever you have tried.

Comment: want to fetch data from assets folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which kind of error do you get? Please tell us more about your problem and post the logcat. This should not be an answer but I need to explain that you have done something wrong:

You wrote for the outputFile:

```
       String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
```

but this will give you the following path:

```
      "/data/data/com.example.mynwedb/databases/wbtywbty";
```

because your `DB_PATH` is

```
      "/data/data/com.example.mynwedb/databases/wbty";
```

and your `DB_NAME` is:

```
      "wbty";
```

I will try to help you if we got more information....

### EDIT

Same in `checkDatabase()`:

```
     String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
```

Comment: thanks for your answer , Actually i'm getting my db file, but i'm stuck while accessing the data from it. plz help..

Comment: ok, and could You please post the logcat to see which kind the error You get?

Comment: i am not getting any error in logcat. I am  getting my db file, but i'm not able to fetch data from it.

Comment: ok sorry for the question again, but I need to know a little bit more. 1. Is copyDataBase() successfull? 2. From which Database You want to fetch, the original or copied one? 3. Is You r problem that You just don´t know how to get the data, because getData(); has no function, there is no code that gets the data?

Comment: actually i want to fetch the data from the original one and also i want to show the data.